# Get a single row based on a max value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this is probably pretty simple but I need some help. I am currently returning multiple rows based on the below query. The licensetypeid column returns two rows with different INTS. I want to return the highest int, and all of the other column information related to it. The columns all have different values.

```
select JdeAddressNo, LicenseNo, ExpirationDate, max(LicenseTypeId) LicenseTypeID
from Licensing_DEV..License 
group by JdeAddressNo, LicenseNo, ExpirationDate
```

I believe my problem is in the group by because all of the other values are different. How can I correct this so I just return the single row with the highest value in the ID column?

Comment: Select Last(<your Id column>) if you want the highest value from the entire table.

Comment: Why can't you use **select top 1**

Comment: select top 1 gives you the first record seen. Not necessarily the highest valued.

Comment: That's not the case if you **use group by..order by desc**. I just didn't expand on that one..

Comment: It is returning multiple rows. So there maybe 20 distinct JDEAddress numbers, but some of them have multiple licensetypes. Hence selecting the TOP would cut out the other rows that I need returned, if that makes sense.

Comment: My idea is sort of 'answered' below by Fred. Check his answer

Comment: I think you all are missing the output. I am returning a ton of rows, some of which have multiple licensetypes. If there are multiple rows returned for a specific address number, I want to only return the row with the highest licensetypeID. So if there is an address with a license type of 1 and 6 returned, I only want to return the record associated with the 6. If there is an address number returned with a license type of 4 and 5, I want it to only return the record associated with the 5.

Comment: "select distinct ..." doesn't work?

Comment: It would have been helpful for you to illustrate that you wanted multiple rows back, limited to one row per customer, with sample data, and desired output.  I have updated my answer based on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    select JdeAddressNo, LicenseNo, ExpirationDate, LicenseTypeId
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JdeAddressNo, LicenseNo, ExpirationDate ORDER BY LicenseTypeId DESC) rn
    from Licensing_DEV..License
   )A
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on the desired output, but this will return the row data associated with the `Max(LicenseTypeId)` for for each `LicenseNo`.

```
    select t.JdeAddressNo, t.LicenseNo, t.ExpirationDate, t.LicenseTypeID
    from Licensing_DEV..License t
    join (select max(LicenseTypeId) as LicenseTypeId, LicenseNo from Licensing_DEV..License group by LicenseNo) m
       on t.LicenseTypeID=m.LicenseTypeID
       and t.LicenseNo=m.LicenseNo
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a94e/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 JdeAddressNo, LicenseNo, ExpirationDate, LicenseTypeId
from Licensing_DEV..License 
group by JdeAddressNo, LicenseNo, ExpirationDate
order by max(LicenseTypeId) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select JdeAddressNo, LicenseNo, ExpirationDate, LicenseTypeID
from Licensing_DEV..License 
where LicenseTypeID = (Select max(LicenseTypeID) from Licensing_DEV..License)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,if you get any error, please post the error and some sample data.

```
SELECT    Top 1 JdeAddressNo, LicenseNo, ExpirationDate, LicenseTypeId
FROM      Licensing_DEV..License 
WHERE     LicenseTypeId = (SELECT MAX(licenseTypeID) FROM Licensing_DEV..License)
GROUP BY  JdeAddressNo, LicenseNo, ExpirationDate 
order by LicenseTypeId  desc
```